# C# WinForm error import from excel to database

Tags: c#, excel, winforms

Hei. I need to understand why I receive an error like that : 
[C# windows form import from excel error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/koTGe.png)

I can't separe the year from string (year time). Or, can I renounce at split and import directly the string as "date"? Sorry, I'm too beginner in c#, but I need this help, is a task for me.

Here is my code :

```
for (int i = 0; i < dvColumns.Count; i++)
            {
                string columnName = string.Empty;
                string columnField = string.Empty;
                if ((dvColumns[i]["Header"] != null) && (!Convert.IsDBNull(dvColumns[i]["Header"])))
                {
                    columnName = dvColumns[i]["Header"].ToString();
                }
                if ((dvColumns[i]["Field"] != null) && (!Convert.IsDBNull(dvColumns[i]["Field"])))
                {
                    columnField = dvColumns[i]["Field"].ToString();
                }

                rangeObject = cellsObject.GetType().InvokeMember("Item", BindingFlags.GetProperty, null, cellsObject, new object[] { row, i + 1 });
                object valueObject = rangeObject.GetType().InvokeMember("Value", BindingFlags.GetProperty, null, rangeObject, null);

                if (columnName == "FiscalCode" && columnField == "PartnerId")
                {  
                    string fiscalCode = Erp.Core.Utils.GetStringFromObject(valueObject);
                    partnerId = p.GetPartnerIdByFiscalCode(fiscalCode);
                    eventRow["PartnerId"] = partnerId;
                }
                else if (columnField == "StartDate" || columnField == "EndDate")
                {
                    string date = Erp.Core.Utils.GetStringFromObject(valueObject);
                    DateTime columnDate = DateTime.Now;
                    string[] dateComponents = null;
                    int year = 0;
                    int month = 0;
                    int day = 0;
                    if (date.Contains("."))
                    {
                        dateComponents = date.Split('.');
                    }
                    if (date.Contains("/"))
                    {
                        dateComponents = date.Split('/');
                    }
                    if (date.Contains(":"))
                    {
                        dateComponents = date.Split(':');
                    }
                    if (dateComponents.Length > 1)
                    {
                        string s = dateComponents[0];
                        day = Erp.Core.Utils.GetIntFromObject(s);
                        s = dateComponents[1];
                        month = Erp.Core.Utils.GetIntFromObject(s);
                        s = dateComponents[2];
                        year = Erp.Core.Utils.GetIntFromObject(s);
                        columnDate = new DateTime(year, month, day, 9, 0, 0);
                    }
                    eventRow[columnField] = columnDate;
                }
                else if (columnField != "PartnerId" && columnField != "StartDate" && columnField != "EndDate")
                {
                    eventRow[columnField] = valueObject;
                }
            }
```

Comment: Did you debug the code and check which line of code is giving error?

Comment: clearly, the error is in your code that constructs DateTime from excel representation. What is format in Excel? In fact, what are you getting in this `date` variable (line `string date = Erp.Core.Utils.GetStringFromObject(valueObject);`)

Comment: Check the day, month, year values in the debugger at the line the error occurs on. What is the value of "date"?

Comment: I tried to keep in excel same format as in database table : 'yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm:ss.000'. The line `date = Erp.Core.Utils.GetStringFromObject(valueObject);` get my date from first excel cell. ds.Tables["Events"] is all time empty. I know this line `eventRow[columnField] = date;` must add the dates in DB, really?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to keep in excel same format as in database table : 'yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm:ss.000'.

The line `date = Erp.Core.Utils.GetStringFromObject(valueObject);` get my date from first excel cell. 
ds.Tables["Events"] is all time empty.

I know this line `eventRow[columnField] = date;` must add the dates in DB, really? After split, day is ok (receive an int by s[0]), month is ok (receive an int by s[1], but s[2] for year is something like 2017 19:06:22 .... year plus time). I tried to split again by space, but without results, to keep the number (2017) in year variable.

Answer (score 0):

Best way is to use `DateTime.ParseExact` method. In your case, if original format is `'yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm:ss.000'`, you can convert it to `DateTime` like this:

```
//string date = Erp.Core.Utils.GetStringFromObject(valueObject);
string date = "2017/08/15 10:20:30.000";
DateTime columnDate = DateTime.ParseExact(date, "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss.fff", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

This way you can skip parsing excel string.
In your example, usage will be like this:

```
//...snip...
else if (columnField == "StartDate" || columnField == "EndDate")
{
    string date = Erp.Core.Utils.GetStringFromObject(valueObject);
    //parsing date string
    DateTime columnDate = DateTime.ParseExact(date, "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss.fff", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

    eventRow[columnField] = columnDate;
}
else if (columnField != "PartnerId" && columnField != "StartDate" && columnField != "EndDate")
{
    eventRow[columnField] = valueObject;
}
```

if hours are in 12-hour format, use lowercase hh, like this `"yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm:ss.fff"`

Comment: if I use this method, receive : `Additional information: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.` for every format

Comment: @AlleXyS90 format string needs to be as same as the one in Excel cell.

Comment: @AlleXyS90 can you show some dates from excel? Are they all in sam format, like yyyy/mm/dd or do they vary like your code suggests (in exampe, date is sometimes with slashes, next time with dots...)

Comment: Yep, is same format in excel: yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm:ss.000. Same in database table where I need to insert these dates.

Comment: @AlleXyS90 is there any row where there's no date, just empty value? That would throw an exception.